# Retrofit response.body returning truncated string if response contains semicolon in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to upload image using retrofit (this is my first attempt), everything is working fine but my response body is getting truncated and getting 12345 instead of "12345;fileName.jpg".

i tried to convert `response.body().toString()` but still not working

**Something.java** ***(Implemented class)***

Header

```
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory; 
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

Implementation

```
File file = new File(filePath);

//creating request body for file
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(fileType), file);

//The gson builder
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

//creating retrofit object
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(this.getString(R.string.pref_upload_url))
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

//creating our api
Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

//creating a call and calling the upload image method
Call<String> call = api.uploadImage(requestFile);

//finally performing the call
call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        String val = response.body().toString();
        if (response.body() != null && response.body().length() > 0 && response.body().charAt(0) != '0') {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

**Api.java**

```
package com.ericsson.wfmmobileapp.android;

import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Part;

public interface Api {

    @Multipart
    @POST("upload.php/")
    Call<String> uploadImage(@Part("file\"; filename=\"myfile.jpg\" ") RequestBody file);
}
```

**Postman output**

[image]

Comment: did you check with the backend code?

Comment: the returning response is actually totally dependent on your back end.
you can make sure of the all the response cases using PostMan App.

Comment: @seyedJafari, Yes I already have checked in postman response is "12345;fileName.jpg"

Comment: @Sujay can you share your working postman request? That might help to figure out issue.

Comment: Backend code is correct (verified in postman first) so as front end request (created other php api to verify) only problem with response with semicolon is getting truncated and getting "12345" instead of "12345;fileName.jpg"

Comment: Hi @BipinVayalu, added postman sceenshot in my question.

Comment: try to remove the gsonConverterFactory see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sayad Jafari, he gave the clue.

`GsonConverterFactory` is to get response in JSON format and semicolon(;) is line termination symbol so i was getting response string till semicolon, I changed my approach used `ScalarsConverterFactory` instead of `GsonConverterFactory`, now it is working.

**Old Header**

```
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory; 
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

**New header**

```
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;
```

**Old Implementation**

```
//The gson builder
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

//creating retrofit object
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(this.getString(R.string.pref_upload_url))
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

**New Implementation**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(this.getString(R.string.pref_upload_url))
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```